# Docker bridges have no-carrier with sytemd-networkd

Tags: docker, systemd-networkd, docker-compose

My docker containers connected to a bridge network aren't able make outbound connections. I found out that two of the bridge networks had no carrier. I believe, I am currently running systemd-networkd as systemd says it's active and enabled. It is not a DNS-related issue as I also can't ping IP-Addresses.

```
networkctl list
[...]
    5 docker0         bridge   routable    unmanaged
    6 br-e9d46f28518e bridge   routable    unmanaged
    7 br-0bf9e6b83ab7 bridge   no-carrier  unmanaged
   67 br-9f2b2355610a bridge   no-carrier  unmanaged
```

### Update 23.02.

I now ran `ip link ls master <interface` for the working an nonworking bridge interfaces:

The routable bridge br-e9d46f28518e:

```
6845: veth031e414@if6844: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-e9d46f28518e state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether aa:9b:14:50:c5:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
6849: veth7ca063a@if6848: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-e9d46f28518e state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 72:5c:64:9e:7e:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 4
6853: vethac1408d@if6852: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-e9d46f28518e state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 56:13:a0:75:9c:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 6
6855: veth6764634@if6854: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-e9d46f28518e state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether ae:38:48:57:79:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 5
```

The no-carrier bridges returned nothing

### Update 24.02.

The bridges have the following ip-Addresses:

#### docker0

```
inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
```

#### br-e9d46f28518e

```
inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-e9d46f28518e
```

#### br-0bf9e6b83ab7

```
inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-0bf9e6b83ab7
```

#### br-9f2b2355610a

```
inet 172.21.0.1/16 brd 172.21.255.255 scope global br-9f2b2355610a
```

### Update 25.02

After actually starting the container again br-06d8960b9155, which corresponds to said container. It is routable though it doesn't have an internet connection. `ip link ls master br-06d8960b9155` shows this:

```
11464: vethc11a61b@if11463: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-06d8960b9155 state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 5e:b8:1f:91:68:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
11466: vethe3b3dc3@if11465: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-06d8960b9155 state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 2e:ee:12:3c:0e:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 3
```

Comment: In this context, no-carrier means: no running container using this bridge. Is there something making you think that shouldn't be the case? Check this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904562/docker-how-to-find-the-network-my-container-is-in and report here what's the status for the running containers with regard to their network(s).

Comment: So, I ran the  container, and it created a new network called br-06d8960b9155b. It's routable, though it doesn't have an internet connection. (Thank you for explaining what no-carrier means in this case). the links corresponding to the bridge are in the Post above.

Comment: I'm now confused about what your question is about.

Comment: It's about how the containers connected to the docker bridge networks are unable to make connections to the internet. (I am very confused as well)

Comment: Looks like a vast and wide topic requiring a lot of troubleshooting and steps rather than a precise problem. I wouldn't be able to answer to this (maybe someone else would).